# Use of "eben" – does it mean just, also or even?

Tags: meaning

I have just heard on Deutschlandfunk:

> es gibt *eben* Menschen, die ...

Does this mean:

- There are *even* people, who ...
- There are *just* people, who ...
- There are *also* people, who ...

Being english, there are subtle differences in meaning between those three alternatives! Can a German please tell me which one it most appropriates to. Danke!

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Does any of these eben-question (there are more https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=eben) answer your question? https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58592/36160 or https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27802/36160 or https://german.stackexchange.com/q/51878/36160 or https://german.stackexchange.com/q/53280/36160 or

Comment: What are the subtle differences in English? The listing of even/just/also is a good starting point, it just does not tell me the subtle difference in usage.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm fairly sure "even" as a translation for "eben" refers to the _adjective_ "even" (as in: level, flat), not the adverb.

Comment: It might be worth checking out the questions posted by Shegit Brahm, but in short, "eben" is used to convey a "*shrug* that's just the way it is"

Comment: Das ist halt so

Comment: In answer to Shegit above, if you say "there are even people", it kind of implies that there is something in addition, or a particular class of people, but it not as final as say, "there are just people" - which is said with almost resignation and implies an inescapable conclusion. Saying "there are also people", just means there are additional people. Even and just are very similar here. Perhaps even is less final in meaning.

Comment: Sorry, I would to expand on the naunces of even. If you say in English, "there are even ...", it is not only saying that there is something in addition, but it gives additional emphasis to something that perhaps would be surprising or previously unknown. For example "there are even Germans who speak Russian", "there are even footballers who went to University", "there are even English people who try to learn languages"!!!! :)

Answer (score 13):

In this context, the appropriate translation of *eben* is *just*.

However, there might be a nuance which does not really translate into English: In assertive statements, *eben* is emphasizing the assertion. It expresses the idea, that the statement is thought to be self-evident, and that the speaker is not expecting it to be called into question. (In some sense, it expresses that the assertion is considered a dogma by the speaker.) I am not sure, how strong this idea is with the English *just*. I feel, that *just* is weaker in English, because I think, *just* is often used as a mere filling-word without any strong significance. But this is a question about English then...

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. On your last point, it would depend on the intonation. I could say, there are just people who always will vote for Trump, whatever the consequences - (with emphasis on the just - and this would have the strong significance (as you say emphasizing the assertion - it would not be a mere filling word). As far as I know, just is not a filler word in English. :)

Comment: In English we would do express this nuance with a rising tone: "there's Just PEOPLE".

Answer (score 11):

In this context I think the right translation would be *simply*.

There are *simply* people who...
Is the closest to

> es gibt *eben* Menschen, die ...

I can think of. It's more like saying that there are people who are x without an explicit explantation to why people are x. Another way to say this in german would be:

> es gibt *einfach* Menschen, die ...

Both can be used in this case

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is my lack of english skills but i am not sure if either of them is the correct translation.

- There are **even** people, who ...

> Es gibt **sogar** Leute, die ...

I believe he would have said

> Es gibt **eben sogar** Leute, die ...

if that was what he meant.

- There are **also** people, who ...

> Es gibt **auch** Leute, die ...

I believe he would have said

> Es gibt **eben auch** Leute, die ...

if that was what he meant.

- There are **just** people, who ...

> Es gibt **nur** Leute, die ...

I think I am not familiar with "just" in this context and it is this alternative.

> Es gibt **eben** Leute, die ...

meant like

> Es gibt Leute, die (...). Das ist **eben** so.

> There are people who (...). That's just how it is.

Comment: hi choXer, thank you. I think it was meant in the context of the last example you said. Es gibt Leute, die. Das ist eben so.

Comment: But indeed “just” can be used in this context. “There are just people...” can mean “it's _just a fact_ that there are people...” though this usage is pretty informal and only works if emphasis is on ‘people’. If the emphasis is on ‘just’, then this corresponds indeed to “es gibt nur Leute...”.

Answer (score 6):

To tell you which of the three alternatives fits best I would have to understand the differences between them, and as you say they may be subtle, so I will not try that.

Just from the small snippet, I expect the meaning to be along the lines of: There are people, who ... This is a fact, ignoring it will not make it otherwise, one has to take this into account and deal with it.

Comment: Thank you Carsten S.

Answer (score 5):

It's key to understand that *eben* is a [modal-particle](/questions/tagged/modal-particle), and as such, adds context-dependent nuance.

A combination of *simply* and *just*, as used in the following quote, is quite close to the intended meaning in your example:

> [But] there are **simply just** people who have legitimate questions and need to have those questions answered [...]

[(said Oct 15, 2020 by an Alabama health official about COVID-19 vaccine critics)](https://www.wbrc.com/2020/10/15/adph-preparing-covid-vaccine-distribution-harris-stresses-public-trust/)

Here, it adds that the statement is to be understood as established, common knowledge which the speaker assumes everyone accepts as an obvious reality.

That is, the speaker doesn't assume they tell you something new, or try to convince you that *there are people who X*, they just restate/remind you of that fact - for the purpose of the actual argument they are about to make.

Comment: Thank you Arminius.

Comment: @GrahamLucas Just as you, I believe, this is a quite good answer. Hence I gave it a +1. In addition, I would like to make you aware of this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment I pretty much agree with the accepted answer there.

Comment: I'm not sure if *simply just* is an accurate translation. *Eben* expresses that what is being said is a fact, as *halt* does, but less colloquially. Nonetheless, it's useful anwer as it mentions that *eben* here is a modal particle.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word *eben* in phrases like this doesn't have much semantic content – it's rather akin to phonetic emphasis. An idiomatic English translation for

> Es gibt eben Menschen, die ...

might be

- There actually are people who ...
- Well, there are people who ...
- Unfortunately, there are people who ...
- There are indeed people who ...
- But there are people who ...

Which of these most faithfully conveys the intended meaning and connotations depends on context. Since you heard this on the radio – prosody is probably a stronger indicator of intent here than mere words. Maybe you can find a link to the program on [deutschlandfunk.de](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de) and we can have a listen... :-)

Comment: Thank you -  you have reinforced my understanding :) Much appreciated.

Comment: I disagree with "no semantic content" - the meaning is very subtle, but words like "eben" (modal particles) do add a specific mood or flavour to the sentence. For instance, I'd say that "But there are people who ..." is _not_ a correct translation, because the "*shrug* that's just how it is" mood conveyed by "eben" rules out the information being new or surprising. For that, you'd want "doch".

Comment: I didn't say "no semantic content". I agree that words like "eben" can add a specific mood or flavour to the sentence, but I'd say that's more pragmatics than semantics.

Comment: I think the "But ..." version might be an appropriate translation in some cases. Depends on context. The "shrug that's just how it is" mood is not the only one that can be conveyed by "eben". Imagine a discussion where someone argues that something may affect few people, but there **are** some it **does** affect. In that case, "es gibt eben Menschen" would have a stress on "**gibt**": "es **gibt** eben Menschen", and it would mean something similar to "but there **are** people who...".

Answer (score 1):

As always in translation, there are two tasks at hand: understanding the source expression and figuring out how to express it in the target language. Being a native speaker of German I can try to help you with the first but not so well with the second.
In line with what Astrid said: what "eben" tells *me* in the above context is

- "as everybody knows", and
- "it cannot be helped".

Let native speakers of English figure out how best to convey these meanings without being wordy.